# Ruby on Rails Stuck on Resolving Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to revive an old project and I'm just seeing:

```
 bundle install
The git source `git://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
Fetching git://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Gem File:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rails'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'sdoc'
gem 'google-analytics-rails'
gem 'slack-notifier'

# Installed by Kessy
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'hirb' # Better irb console output
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'countries'
gem 'delayed_paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
gem 's3_direct_upload'
gem 'faker'
gem 'populator'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'decent_exposure'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'stripe', git: 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'pghero'
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'gritter'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'money'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'formvalidation-rails'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'has_secure_token'
gem 'bootstrap_tokenfield_rails'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'seedbank'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'oj'
gem 'pgbackups-archive'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'pry'

  # Added by Kessy
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'rails-dev-boost'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'brakeman'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma'
end

# Docs say place at
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Ruby 2.5.1

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/EhG9VVas

Comment: Try using `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle --verbose` to see what it's trying to resolve and where it's getting stuck.

Comment: Not sure what's happening: https://pastebin.com/EhG9VVas

Comment: Do you have `Gemfile.lock` within the project?

Comment: I've removed it.